# Breaking down だと感じる

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words, syntax

In the sentence: 
日本人がアメリカを旅行して面倒だと感じることの一つは、チップの習慣である。

I understand that it means something along the lines of 
"One of the troubling experiences of Japanese people who travel to america is the custom of tipping."

I don't understand why it's written as 面倒だと感じることの一つは
Why not 面倒なことの一つは?
Can someone please break down the usage of だと感じる

is the と being used for quoting purposes, to mean "when/if" or is the だと the expression "if it's the case"? 
I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: The 「と」 used here is the quotative/case particle (格助詞)「と」. 「と」 meaning "when/if" is the conjunctive particle (接続助詞)「と」.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `面倒なことの一つは` sounds judgmental and from the writer's perspective while `面倒だと感じることの一つ` sounds more anecdotal and from other peoples' perspectives. When you say `だと感じる` its saying that other people feel a certain way. "One thing that Japanese people find/feel is annoying / difficult"

Comment: is the と being used for quoting purposes, to mean "when/if" or is the だと the expression "if it's the case"?

Comment: its just the grammatical usage of N+quotation. The `と` in this case operates similar to a quote. I think if you just try to translate it as if it were "if that's the case" you can easily see that the sentence wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: I see, sorry for the dumb questions. Thanks!

Comment: no worries! it isn't always so clear cut